# C singly linked list using Queue

Tags: c, queue, computer-science, singly-linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "locker.h"


void QueueInit(Queue* p)
{
    p->front = NULL;
    p->rear = NULL;
}

int QIsEmpty(Queue* p)
{
    if(p->front == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void Enqueue(Queue* p, int data)
{
    Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->id = data;

    if(QIsEmpty(p))
    {
        p->front = newNode;
        p->rear = newNode;
    } else {
        p->rear->next = newNode;
        p->rear = newNode;
    }
}

void attachEnqueue(Queue* p, int user_id)
{
    Node* temp = p->front;
    temp->user_id = user_id;    
    p->front = temp;

    printf("Locker %d Owned By %d\n", temp->id, temp->user_id);

    temp->owned = 1;

    temp = temp->next;

}

int Dequeue(Queue* p)
{
    Node* temp = p->front;
    uint16_t item;

    if(QIsEmpty(p))
    {
        printf("No element exists!");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        item = temp->id;
        p->front = temp->next;
        free(temp);

        if(temp == NULL)
        {
            p->rear = NULL;
        }
        return (item);
    }
}

void printList(Queue* p) 
{
    Node* v = p->front;
    while(v != NULL){ 
        printf("Locker: %d\n", v->id);
        v = v->next;
    }
}

int count (Queue p)
{
    int c = 0 ;
    Node* temp = p.front ;

    while ( temp != NULL )
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        c++ ;
    }

    return c ;
}

void SearchQueue(Queue* p, int val1)
{
    Node* v = p->front;
    int sw = 0;

    while( v != NULL)
    {
        if(v->id == val1)
        {
            printf("Locker ID: %d\n", val1);
            printf("Lock Status: locked\n");

            if(v->owned == 0){
            printf("unowned\n");
            } else if(v->owned == 1)
            {
            printf("owned by %d\n", v->user_id);
        }
            sw = 1;
        }
        v = v->next;
    }
    if(!sw)
    {
        printf("locker %d does not exists\n", val1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Queue queue;
    QueueInit(&queue);

    char input[50];
    char command[20];
    int val1;
    uint16_t id = 1;


    while(1)
    {
        scanf(" %49[^\n]s", input);
        sscanf(input, "%s %d", &command, &val1);

        if(strcmp(command, "CREATE") == 0)
        {
            printf("New Locker created: %d\n", id);
            Enqueue(&queue, id);
            id++;

        } else if(strcmp(command, "DISPLAY") == 0)
        {
            SearchQueue(&queue, val1);

        } else if(strcmp(command, "ATTACH") == 0)
        {
            attachEnqueue(&queue, val1);    

        } else if(strcmp(command, "DISPLAYALL") == 0)
        {
            printList(&queue);

        }else if(strcmp(command, "DELETE") == 0)
        {
            printf("Deleted the locker, %d\n",Dequeue(&queue)); 

        }else if(strcmp(command, "QUIT") == 0)
        {
            printf("Good Bye!\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        continue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have so far and the contents for "locker.h" is:

```
#ifndef LOCKER_H
#define LOCKER_H
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct locker_t {
  uint16_t id;
  uint16_t user_id;
  uint8_t locked;
  uint8_t owned;
  int write_fd;
  int read_fd;
      struct locker_t* next;
    }Node;

typedef struct queue_t {
  Node* front;
  Node* rear;
  size_t size;
}Queue;

#endif
```

Everything works fine except for the attachEnqueue part.
The purpose is, when I create locker 1 and locker 2 and input ATTACH 20,
locker 1's owner should be 20 and again if I input ATTACH 30, locker 2`s owner should be 30.

However, when I create 2 lockers and firstly ATTACH 20 and then again input ATTACH 30, the locker 1's owner`s value only changes from 20 to 30, not assigning the 30 owner to locker 2.

I am 100% sure that the attachEnqueue function involves the wrong contents but I am really not sure how to modify it..

Also, I need to include a "LOCK" command to make the locker whether to be locked or unlocked, but the problem is, school wants me to do this by using signal SIGUSR. How should I use the signal function to lock or unlock the locker? Would pthread.mutex.lock and unlock work?

Any help or advice would be very thankful!

Comment: Your `attachEnqueue` always updates the head of the list. You have made no attempt to implement the logic you have described. You need to init the `user_id` fields with an invalid/unused value (or use a seperate "unattached" flag field). Then `attachEnqueue` needs to traverse the list until it finds such a value.

Answer (score 0):

The comment is right. The last line of `attachEnqueue` is `temp = temp->next;`
Maybe you assume `temp` keeps that information in mind next time you call the function, but right now, absolutely not. This line is of no use, the next time, `temp` will be assigned to the front of the queue.
To go around that, you may create a flag in your struct as stated above, add a counter argument to your function to keep track of which element in your queue to attach, or make `temp` a static argument, so its state persists between calls.